# Relation of EditText with its Id in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

**Please Read My Question Carefully**

I am learning `Activity` `LifeCycle`**. I only have one `EditText` and a `TextView` in my XML layout With certain `id`. When I rotate the screen, nothing seems to change because Rotation doesn't affect `EditText`**. But when I remove the `id` of `EditText` in `XML` and rotated the screen, The Rotation Starts affecting and the text in the `editText` removed due to rotation. I am confused about the relation of `EditText` with its Id.

### I tried to explain the problem below in columns:

**Explanation of below Column names**

- Having Id: Does EditText has id?
- Rotation : Phone has Rotated or not
- EditText : What happen to EditText After Rotation.

.

`Having Id`----------------`Rotation`---------------`EditText`

```
Yes                  Rotated            Does not change

No                   Rotated             Yes, Text Removed from editText
```

**`MainActivity.java` is empty and `main_activity.xml` code is below:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter here"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.371" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

***Sorry for using bad English and High-resolution pictures as I have no other ways. Best Regards***

Comment: Are you trying to acheive something here?

Comment: Please read my whole question again. Actually I don't want to lose my editText data after Rotation. But when I remove my editText id, my data is getting lost after rotation. So I want to know the relation of EditText with its id... if you know the answer then please elaborate it otherwise click UpVote so others could also see it quickly.

Comment: can you provide java and xml codes?

Comment: MainActivity is fully empty but I have added the code of XML layout.

Comment: Your problem is solved?

Comment: No man, There are many ways to not lose data on rotation but I just wanted to know the relation of  `editText` with its `id`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most important aspects in Android programming is to handle the configuration changes and most common of them is orientation changes. Although it is not recommended to handle configuration changes yourself, due to the hidden complexity of handling the configuration changes, there are cases where we might need to handle manually.

If you need to save the state, the common approach is to implement `onSaveInstanceState` to store & restore the values which are passed as Bundle.

**Coming back to your question:**

```
Relation of EditText with its Id in Android Studio?
```

When it comes to saving state of `View` Android OS automatically calls the `View.onSaveInstanceState` method on each of the views in your view hierarchy as long as you call through to the super method in `onSaveInstanceState`. In order to restore the data, it uses `android:id` attribute key for that particular View’s state.So for your case, when you don't provide the `id` for `EditText`, the View's state won't be stored due to missing key.

Hope this clarifies the relationship of `id` to `EditText`

Comment: Finally, you gave me the answer. Thanks

Comment: No problem. @ShoaibK.

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate screen on android all activities and fragments in your application are destroyed and then recreated. Android does this so that your application can reload resources based on the new configuration.

When the system destroys the activity (e.g. when the screen rotates) then although the actual Activity instance is gone, the system remembers that it existed. The system creates a new instance of that activity using a set of saved data that describes the state of the activity when it was destroyed.

when your assign an id to a view it seems that android keeps track of that view. Hence it remembers it's state.

Comment: well, I don't think so because Android doesn't track id or remember its state.

Answer (score 0):

Okay when you rotate the device this is considered as a configuration change, so the system recreates the activity and data is lost.

One way to avoid this is go to the manifest and for your specific activity add this

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

here:

```
<activity
android:name=".YourActivityName"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
....
...
```

This makes the system ignore the rotation of device.

Comment: EditText has not relation with rotation. Like if you rotate your device, the editText text would never change or lost But when you remove the id of EditText in XML and then rotate the device the text in editText got lost as shown in above last two pictures Now the question arises that what is the relation of EditText with an id that without id its text getting lost on rotation?

Comment: I have no idea about why this happens.

Comment: you can use my approach and see if it still happens.

Comment: Ok then please UpVote this question so others could see this quickly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`EditText` is a focused view, so in `PhoneWindow`, it's state will be saved automatically in `saveHierarchyState()` method. Only `EditText` with id is going to save text.

Comment: Then why it didn't save in my case?

Comment: Only EditText with id is going to save text.

Answer (score 0):

In manifest of your app, add this line to **activity** tag:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

The reason for this is due to Android basically destroying the activity and creating it again every time you rotate the device. This is mainly to allow for different layouts based on portrait/landscape mode.

When you use `id` for your component, data will be assigned to its `id`, but when it hasn't `id`, it will be recreated and data will be disappeared after rotation.

See these questions and read their good answers, I don't copy and paste them:

1- [TextView's text disappearing when device rotated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879474/textviews-text-disappearing-when-device-rotated)

2- [Handle screen rotation without losing data - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126845/handle-screen-rotation-without-losing-data-android)

Comment: Yes, I added that in `EditText` and it didn't work because my case is different from the one you provided the link. Please read my question again.

Comment: Okay,if data is assigned to it's id then why other type of data is not saved in id... For example, if i add a TextView and count button, when i will press on count button the value in textview will be increment while textview having its id the data of textview would disappear after rotation ... Hence android does not assign data to id. Am i right?

Comment: It's this way for edittext maybe, for textview you can use another things for example freezestext @ShoaibK.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the relation of one specific EditText item to its id is: "one to one" or "one to N". One EditText item in one layout.xml has one id, if you've configured it in the layout.xml. If you've defined more than one layout.xml's and the very same EditText item (having the same id) in more than one layout.xml's, then EditText has a "one to N" relation.